# Image of non-constant entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[how to show image of a non constant entire function is dense in $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337154/819094)

Here answer is given.But I have a doubt.

In the proof using Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem,
it is proved that f can have only finitely many terms.

Thus $f=a_0+a_z+...+a_n z^n.$

Then Fundamental theorem of Algebra guarantees that f have n roots in $\mathbb{C}$,
But how can we say f is constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point in the proof it has been established that $|f(z)-\alpha|>0$ for all $z$. So the polynomial $p(z) = f(z)-\alpha$ has no roots. If it is non-constant you have a contradiction to the fundamental theorem of Algebra.

Comment: Thank you.I understand.